# redirect login page to welcome page from angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating s web app in which i need to redirect from login to welcome page if my user id and password validated

```
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval) {
        //login
        $scope.loginbutton = function () {
            $http.get('/login.asmx/loginuser', {
                params: {
                    log: $scope.log,
                    pm: $scope.pm,
                    password: $scope.password
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                {
                   //here i want to redirect to another page
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

this is my script of angularjs how i redirect the page to another page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add $window in your controller

```
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $location, $window) {
```

then add the following line in your response

```
.then(function (response) {
                    {
                        $window.location.href = "../welcome/Index";
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the $location service, for example:

```
<br>$location.path('/home')<br>
```

here is the ref guid [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)  for more information

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['$location']);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $location) { // add $location dependency in the 
        //login
        $scope.loginbutton = function () {
            $http.get('/login.asmx/loginuser', {
                params: {
                    log: $scope.log,
                    pm: $scope.pm,
                    password: $scope.password
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                {
                    $location.path('google.com') //pass the url in it.
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$state` to redirect

controller.js

```
controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $state) {
    $scope.loginbutton = function () {
        $http.get('/login.asmx/loginuser', {
            params: {
                log: $scope.log,
                pm: $scope.pm,
                password: $scope.password
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {
             $state.go('page');
        })
    }
});
```

Then in your route.js you need to specify the new state to redirect to.

```
angular.module('app.routes', []);
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

        .state('page', {
            url: '/page',
            templateUrl: 'templates/page.html',
            controller: 'pageCtrl'
       })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `$location` dependency in your controller and need to call `$location.url('/login')` to navigate to login page. I have modified your code for this.

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $location) {
        //login
        $scope.loginbutton = function () {
            $http.get('/login.asmx/loginuser', {
                params: {
                    log: $scope.log,
                    pm: $scope.pm,
                    password: $scope.password
                }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                {
                   //Navigate to welcome page
                   $location.url('/welcome');
                }
            })
        }
    });
</script>
```

You should need a `welcome` path defined in your route provider like.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute'
    ])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/landing.html',
            controller: 'landingController'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/customers', {
            templateUrl: 'views/customers.html',
            controller: 'customersCtrl'
        });
        $routeProvider.when('/welcome', {
            templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
            controller: 'welcomeController'
        });
        ..............
        ..............
        $routeProvider.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/login'
        });
    }]);
})();
```